# Python regex or other solution to extract text items from a string?

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup, text-mining

I have a string that lookls like this:

```
\nInhaltse / techn. Angaben*\n\nAQUA • COCO-GLUCOSIDE • COCOSULFATE • SODIUM\n\n\
```

And I need to get a list of the items between dots, as follows:

```
AQUA COCO-GLUCOSIDE COCOSULFATE  SODIUM
```

I have tried with regex and other tools but I cant find the right, flexible* answer.

*flexible = the list might have something between 1 and N elements

Comment: You could do it in two steps  - get a part in caps and dots with a regex, then use `split()` to get the list of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a little bit better what are the possibilities, and which rules you want to apply.
I think that a rule like *'any word with only at least 2 uppercase characters or dash preceded and followed by a space or \n'* may work for you. If thats the case, here's your RegEx:

```
import re

my_string = "\nInhaltse / techn. Angaben*\n\nAQUA • COCO-GLUCOSIDE • COCOSULFATE • SODIUM\n\n"

print(re.findall(r"(?<=\n|\s)[A-Z-]{2,}(?=\n|\s)", my_string))
```

Output:

> ['AQUA', 'COCO-GLUCOSIDE', 'COCOSULFATE', 'SODIUM']

and here's how you read the RegEx:

`(?<=\n|\s)` means *preceded by (*`?<=`*) a new line(*`\n`*) or (*`|`*) a space (*`\s`*)*
`[A-Z-\s]{2,}` means *at least two (*`{2,}`*) uppercase letters, dash and spaces (*`[A-Z-\s]`*)*
`(?=\n|\s)` means *followed by (*`?=`*) a new line(*`\n`*) or (*`|`*) a space (*`\s`*)*

or for fitting better your request:

> get a list of the items between dots

you may use:

```
r"(?<=\n\n|\•\s)[A-Z-\s]{2,}(?=\n\n|\s\•)"
```

which means:

> at least 2 uppercase letters, dash or spaces, preceded by two new line or a dot and a space and followed by two new lines or a space and a dot

Comment: Almost there! It is not working for the cases like this, with 2 words items: \nInhaltse / techn. Angaben*\n\nAQUA • COCO-GLUCOSIDE • COCO DISULFATE • NITRATE SODIUM\n\n\

Comment: as you can see, the part of the regex that matches the words is `[A-Z-]{2,}`. We simply have to add that we also accept spaces: `[A-Z-\s]{2,}`; btw I'll update also the answer